# Change all image url to another url

Tags: regex, apache

I've been trying to change image src url to another based on a condition. We have some urls that are stored on our database such as `/0/0/90/foo/bar.jpg` and some `http://www.foo.com/foo/bar.jpg`.

Is it possible, in apache, to change all these image source? Any image that starts with or match `/0/0/90/*` changes to `http://foo.com/0/0/90/*`?

`*` is a wildcard for any name/paths.

When on localhost, the images uses `localhost/0/0/90/` when we want all images to point to the `www.foo.com/0/0/90/*` domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as top rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^0/0/90/ http://foo.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```